# Retrieve deleted Facebook message

Tags: c++, xcode

I have searched but it seems that any thread I find picks up from somewhere in the middle of a project.

I want to gain access to a Facebook message that I wrote almost 10 months ago. It was the first contact that I made with my long lost love. I know, it's korny and I should have at least remembered that date.

Can anyone help me get started? I have limited/semi novice skills. I am willing to do the research but I just need a nudge in the right direction. This isn't an assignment, it's rather a challenge to find it and surprise her with it.

I am not sure if it can even be done.

Answer (score 1):

For having messed a lot (too much) with Facebook messaging system, I can tell you won't be able to retrieve a deleted message. Facebook will not return deleted messages with the others and there is no special function for that, sorry I believe that's the intent behind message deletion.